# 'Login Failed for User' with Successful Test Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to build a production version of my first C# application, both hosted on Amazon.  While creating a first user during the initial run, an `[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'databaseuser'.]` is thrown even though the login credentials can connect successfully.  Can anyone see why?  Many thanks in advance, because I'm exasperated.  The details and what I've tried are:

The test database is on SQL Express and its schema has been imported into an instance of SQL Server Standard Edition;  The testing Visual Studio folder, which runs successfully, has been copied to another location using Windows Explorer and renamed for production;  The production Web.config connection strings have been changed to the production SQL instance and the corresponding username and password;  The login tests successfully in the Server Explorer's "Test Connection", the `.edmx` Model Browser Add/Update stored procedures, and directly logging into SQL Server with the "databaseuser" credentials.  The SQL instance is set to SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.  The "databaseuser" has read/write permissions on both databases in the SQL instance.

**Code fails here in `public class AccountMembershipService : IMembershipService`**

```
private MembershipProvider _provider;
public MembershipCreateStatus CreateUser(string userName, string password, string email)
{
    MembershipCreateStatus status;
    _provider.CreateUser(userName, password, email, null, null, true, null, out status);
    //FAIL ON THE ABOVE LINE!        
    return status;
}
```

**Web.config Connection Strings**

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
          connectionString="Server=[production endpoint];
          Database=UsersDb;User ID=databaseuser;Password=[password];
          Trusted_Connection=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />
     <add name="WorkplaceEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Workplace.csdl|
          res://*/Data.Workplace.ssdl|res://*/Data.Workplace.msl;
          provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
          data source=[production endpoint];initial catalog=Workplace;user id=databaseuser;
          password=[password];MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
          providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
     <add name="UsersDbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/
          Data.UsersDb.csdl|res://*/Data.UsersDb.ssdl|res://*/
          Data.UsersDb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
          provider connection string=&quot;data source=[production endpoint];
          initial catalog=UsersDb;user id=databaseuser;password=[password];
          MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
          providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'databaseuser'.]
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +347
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +141
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +362
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +36
    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +138
    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +477
    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32() +520
    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +34
    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +251
    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +196
    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +276
    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +546
    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +151
    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +287
    System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +111
    System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +236
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +143
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +207
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +42
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +136
    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update() +33
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +175
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +150
    System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +445
    System.Data.Entity.Database.Create() +31
    System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.EnsureDatabaseCreated(DbContext db) +160
    System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMembershipContext(ConnectionStringSettings setting) +115
    System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.Membership_CreateUser(String applicationName, String userName, String password, String salt, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, DateTime& createDate, Boolean uniqueEmail, Int32 passwordFormat, Object& providerUserKey) +193
    System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status) +1401
    FirstApp.Controllers.AccountMembershipService.CreateUser(String userName, String password, String email) in c:\My Stuff\FirstApp\FirstApp\firstapp.mvc\Controllers\AccountController.cs:473
    FirstApp.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\My Stuff\FirstApp\FirstApp\firstapp.mvc\Controllers\AccountController.cs:98
    lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +101
    System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
    System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +435
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9744373
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: When you test your login with _databaseuser_, can you change to database _UsersDb_? I suggest you try a UDL file to test your connection: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/michaelgriswold/2014/01/06/the-easy-way-to-test-sql-connectivity/

Comment: Thanks for the response, Nick!  I've not heard of UDL files before, so I'm looking into that, but would you mind clarifying "change to database UsersDb"?  The "databaseuser" can log into SQL directly and query both databases, and the connectivity in the Server Explorer is successful via the "Test Connection" for both databases.

Comment: I just came across this error the other day when it said 'login failed' but actually the login worked fine, the user just couldn't access their default database. However from your description it sounds like this isn't the issue.

Comment: I just created a UDL file and used it to test the connection to UsersDb, which succeeded.  It sure seems like everything necessary to connect is being done and works, so this is confounding.

Comment: Is your IIS running on a different computer? You need to set up AWS firewalls to allow incoming connections from your web server. Also check the SQL Server logs. Connect using SQL Server Management Studio (Description here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187109.aspx). You should find entries in the log indicating that a login failed and hopefully there will be more information about why. _or_ you'll find nothing in the log which means either you're connecting to a different server or your connection doesn't make it that far

Comment: IIS is running on my computer on which the app is being programmed.  I'll check AWS firewalls.  In SQL, there don't appear to be any log files ("Log file summary: No log source").  Given the connections test successfully, why would the connections not make it that far?

Comment: If your IIS is on the same computer and a UDL test works on the same computer I wouldn't bother testing firewalls. Make sure you're checking the SQL Server logs, not the SQL Agent logs. The SQL Server logs should have things like 'server is listening on','sql server is ready for client connections' etc. Unless AWS has some trick to it like this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.SQLServer.html

Comment: The SQL Server Error Logs described in the link you posted show no details available.  This leads me to believe there's something in the Visual Studio code preventing this specific operation from occurring.  Would there be anything not originally mentioned that's a holdover from the copied test code still referencing the test server, using the test UsersDb GUID, etc., and overruling the Web.config and other changes?

Comment: If the UDL works OK then yes that's the next thing - step through the code line by line and see what connection string etc. it is using. I'm not completely familiar with VS deployment methods. It seems to me that you can actually connect to the DB OK, but something inside the `CreateUser` method is not doing what you expect. In particular the error doesn't mention which host you're connecting to, and I've seen plenty of questions on here where the real error is hidden under error handling (though again doesn't seem to be the case)

Comment: ... and if you're interested, as far as I can tell it seems that the AWS SQL Server logs might not be accessed in the normal way, you need to use the console to get to them: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.SQLServer.html.

Comment: Thanks again Nick.  I'll post again when I've found the logs in AWS or gotten into the workings of CreateUser, which I think is a Microsoft method from System.Web.Security namespace.

Comment: Good luck with that. If `CreateUser` is compiled into a class then I would suggest pursuing the SQL Server logs. Then you might get a more useful message. I'm now quite curious about AWS. I guess this an RDS instance, not a VM with SQL Server on it?

Comment: That's correct, it's an RDS instance.  I'll search for the logs, but I fear this is an issue with CreateUser.

Comment: I was curious so I ran up my own and yes you're absolutely right - the logs are no in the usual place. If you expand your instance and press the Logs button you can check them though. I just intentionally logged in with an incorrect password and saw the message: _2016-12-20 14:17:03.45 Logon Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: x.y.z.a]_. So if you are still interested you might want to try that and see if you have a more informative error message.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!  AWS does indeed have the logs.  The error message is "Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided."  I wonder if that means some other password is declared in the CreateUser chain, because the password in the connection strings passes all connectivity tests.

Comment: aha! Now we're getting somewhere. We both learnt something new here which is a bonus. Now I suggest you open your UDL file in notepad and compare that connection string to the one in your app. It might be that for example the password attribute is mispelt.

Comment: I tried substituting the admin credentials in the connection strings, and the code ran properly.  It would appear to me that this, combined with the previous successful connection tests, indicates the issue is really one of permissions on the "databaseuser" even though the error says the login failed.  Would you agree?

Comment: hmmm I'm not totally convinced. If you repeated your UDL test with 'databaseuser' with an incorrect password you would get the 'incorrect password' message in the log. I do way more DB development than App development so I my suspicions lie in the deployment, rightly or wrongly. Another experiment is to grab the connection string out of a functioning UDL file and paste that directly into your prod web.config and see if it works. Also, there is no confusion between the login/password passed into the `CreateUser` method and the login/password used in the connection string is there?

Comment: The UDL incorrect password test resulted in an "incorrect password" log entry, as you said.  The connection string wasn't changed for the admin test except for credentials, so I think the format and server are correct.  It's possible that "CreateUser" is referencing other credentials, but that's just by my logic.  I'm having a tough time tracking down what actually goes on behind the scenes with that Microsoft method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this worked, but here's what apparently cured the problem: I removed the Web.config credentials for "databaseuser" with only read/write access and replaced them with the database admin credentials.  The application tested successfully.  The administrator credentials were then replaced with the original "databaseuser" credentials, and everything works.  It seems like for some reason the application needed the admin to access the connection for the first time, then the read/write user could thenceforth do the same.

Thank you to Nick.McDermaid for the answers.  They're all correct and were being done, but for some reason the program needed the admin to first show it the way.